# unable to locate a 'Type' by the name: ''. Be sure to execute a query or call fetchMetadata first

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I've referenced all existing threads related to the same issue and didn't find any help.

Basically, I'm creating an EntityError collection which contains some validation errors. I add EntityErrors to this collection as follows:

```
   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(user.UserCode))
            {
                if (_usersRepo.HasUserCode(user.Id, user.UserCode, clientId))
                {
                    entityErrors.Add(new EntityError() { EntityTypeName = entityTypeName, ErrorMessage = "UserCode already exist", ErrorName = errorName, PropertyName = "UserCode", KeyValues = new object[] { user.UserCode } });
                }
            }
```

Then I throw the collection as follows:

```
throw new EntityErrorsException(validationErrors);
```

I get the above mentioned error, only after introducing the KeyValues in to the EntityError object, without that the errors are thrown to the application and displayed correctly.

As some of the previous posts have suggested, I tried adding `Manager.FetchMetaData` before calling this validation, but still it didn't work.

Following are the http responses when I get the error vs when it works as expected. You can see that when the error is thrown, KeyValues has a value, and when it works KeyValues is null.

When it works:

```
{"$id":"1","$type":"Breeze.ContextProvider.SaveError, Breeze.ContextProvider","Message":"Exception of type 'Breeze.ContextProvider.EntityErrorsException' was thrown.","EntityErrors":[{"$id":"2","$type":"Breeze.ContextProvider.EntityError, Breeze.ContextProvider","ErrorName":"Attribute Validation Error","EntityTypeName":"Users","KeyValues":null,"PropertyName":"UserCode","ErrorMessage":"UserCode already exist"}]}
enter code here
```

When it errors:

```
{"$id":"1","$type":"Breeze.ContextProvider.SaveError, Breeze.ContextProvider","Message":"Exception of type 'Breeze.ContextProvider.EntityErrorsException' was thrown.","EntityErrors":[{"$id":"2","$type":"Breeze.ContextProvider.EntityError, Breeze.ContextProvider","ErrorName":"Attribute Validation Error","EntityTypeName":"Users","KeyValues":["782"],"PropertyName":"UserCode","ErrorMessage":"UserCode already exist"}]}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the EntityTypeName matches the name in your metadata?

Comment: Yes, and you see - when it errors and when it works, both time the entitytypename is the same.

Comment: I think you should be using `user.Id` as the key value, not `user.UserCode`.  What is the primary key of the entity?

Comment: the key is user.Id

Comment: Then you should use `KeyValues = new object[] { user.Id }`.  But I don't know if that will fix the error.